# How to set Execution timer in a Form to find the duration of the form running.?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to Ax 2012, and now I want to find the running time of the Form where I was filtering the balance of the Vendor based on the Accounting Unit for the specific date range.
I have used two Date Edit (FromDate & ToDate), and Button to filter data.

I want to get Execution time of the Form..

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? E.g. [Trace Parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/s-e/ax/ax_traceparser_34) is a tool that can be used to analyze performance of AX 2012.